# Create Custom Column using csv_from_result in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am trying to create a csv file from the query

```
    $query = "SELECT username AS 'MATRIC NUMBER' FROM table
    WHERE field1 = '$data1' AND field2 = '$data2'";
```

and want the heading of my CSV file to be

```
    "MATRICULATION NUMBER, TEST, EXAM"
```

instead of what will be returned

```
    "MATRICULATION NUMBER"
```

only. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you doing with the [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) riddled code when CodeIgniter has a whole database layer to handle this?

Comment: @tadman I know just 4 questioning purpose

Comment: There's a Codeigniter way to do this that's probably a lot easier.

Comment: @tadman If u know a better way to get a custom heading as my question. please let me know